# I don't know how this solution works

Tags: trigonometry

In triangle ABC, AB = 10cm, BC = 7cm and angle BAC = 40°
(a) Find, in degrees to the nearest 0.1°, the two possible sizes of angle ACB.

(b) Find, in cm to 3 significant figures, the difference between the two possible lengths of AC.

I came across this when looking through the edexcel further pure maths past papers
I got question (a) pretty easily,
i also got  question(b) using the cosine rule,and the answer is also correct but
When i read through the mark scheme
the solution given is by drawing a isosceles triangle BCC',
then finding half of the base length CC"=7cos 66.67° and doubling CC'. 
How does this method works?I cannot seem to understand it.

Here is the link to the mark scheme.
The question number is 5.
https://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/International%20GCSE/Further%20Pure%20Mathematics/2009/Exam%20materials/4PM0_01_rms_20170823.pdf

Comment: To find location of point $C$ first construct $AB$ and then angle $BAC$. There will be two ways to construct the angle. Then draw a height from $BC$, this will give you two right triangles and you can find all angles and sides.

Comment: Draw in their figure from 5(b) the point C'' as the mid point of the base CC' of the isosceles triangle BCC' with BC = BC' = 7. We know from the previous point the angle in C', then consider the triangle BCC", using the cos of <)C' get first C'C", then double it to get CC', the wanted difference.

Comment: The given data (Side-Side-Angle) is not enough to determine a [Congruence of triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Congruence_of_triangles). In this case two separate triangles can be constructed, that is [The ambiguous case of triangle solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#The_ambiguous_case_of_triangle_solution)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ,guys